# How do I call .NET from c++ in as a platform-independent way as possible

Tags: c++, .net, windows, macos, interop

I have a C++ app from which I want to call .NET (C#) methods. I was going to use `C++/CLI`, but it is only supported on Windows.

Since also we support the MAC, I'd like to call .NET from C++ in a way that will work on both Windows and Mac (with Mono).

What is the best way to do this?

EDIT: I should add that the c# code we wish to call is not ours. We have no way of making any changes to it. The c++ code, of course, is ours.

Comment: Great question. I'm curious to see what people come up with.

Comment: I wonder, does Mac/Mono support DCOM?

Comment: A possible solution is to emulate RPC by using [Google's Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) plus sockets. The Protocol Buffers has a [.NET implementation](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to expose the functionality via a function pointer.  Both .Net and native code can interop with C/C++ code in the form of a function pointer.  Function pointers are supported on all platforms where C++ code runs hence it can be written without any understanding of .Net.

Comment: @AndrewS the term to use in search is "Reverse PInvoke".  Here are a couple of articles on the subject http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2006/01/13/512436.aspx

Comment: Thank you - once I had the search term, I found lots of information. One issue though: reverse pInvoke seems to need a delegate on the c# side - but we don't own that code. Is there a way to "just" call the c# methods directly?

Comment: @AndrewS. unfortunately no. In order to call the c# code you need some mechanism to cross the native / managed boundaries. From the native side you really only have 2 options: Reverse pinvoke of a delegate or COM interop.

Comment: In that case, I am considering writing a very thin c# layer that has the necessary delegates which in turn calls the 3rd party c# routines.

Comment: @AndrewS. that sounds like the approach that i would be taking here

Comment: One important point here is to make sure the delegate you use in interop doesn't get garbage collected.